# Building an application within a Joomla website?

Tags: php, python, django, joomla

I'm attempting to build an application to aid engineers and designers in laying out o-ring grooves for sealing applications, a bit like [this one.](http://www.applerubber.com/oring-gland-calculator/)

I'd like to host it on my own [website.](http://www.castorengineering.com) The website is built on Joomla, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to integrate it. Ideally, the app shouldn't require Java or JS/ActiveX (as these are often blocked by modern browsers), but I'd also prefer to stay away from requiring a form submission to complete the calculations. I'm well versed in Python but have no experience with Django, and wonder if it might fit the bill for these requirements.

Right now the fallback solution is just to go with PHP and form submissions. If there is a way to get around that with Django or any other framework, I'd love to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python is not really capable of anything different than php. its just better organised. i think the solution to your wish of not having to use forms would be a heavy dose of javascript, html5 and ajax. also you need to think about how you want to include it in your joomla site. joomla is php, joomla components are written using php however it is possible to incorporate pretty much any web app with an iframe. but it tends to be ugly. so i'd recommend php over python in this case.

Comment: I agree that python isn't really capable of much (if any) more than PHP, I was really just considering getting around form submissions without JS. It looks like I won't be able to do that.